# Quoting items in an array with backticks?

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```js
let list = "none, inherit, circle, disc, decimal, lower-alpha, lower-latin, lower-greek, lower-roman, upper-alpha, upper-latin, upper-greek, upper-roman";
let a = list.split(',').map(s => s.trim());
console.log(a);
let quoted = '';
a.forEach(t => quoted += `'${t}, '`);
console.log(quoted);
```

I'm expecting it to log single quotes around each item in the list, but the list comes out like this:

```
'none, ''inherit, ''circle, ''disc, ''decimal, ''lower-alpha, ''lower-latin, ''lower-greek, ''lower-roman, ''upper-alpha, ''upper-latin, ''upper-greek, ''upper-roman,
```

(I have a feeling I'm brain farting this but ...) Thoughts on why the `'${t}, '` expression is not coming out the way I think it should?  I'm trying to get this:

```
'none', 'inherit', 'circle', 'disc', 'decimal' ...
```

Comment: Why was that unexpected? Each item is surrounded by quotes, with the comma inside: `'${t}, '`. Did you want e.g. `'${t}', ` - what *was* the expected output?

Comment: You want `quoted += \`'${t}', \``  (comma outside the single quotes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this

```
a.forEach(t => quoted += `'${t}, '`);
```

to this

```
a.forEach(t => quoted += `'${t}', `);
```

Comment: Or you could just use `join`: `\`'${list.split(',').map(s => s.trim()).join("', '")}'\``

Comment: Nice tip - I'll be adding that!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just use `.split()` with a comma and a space delimiter then `.join("', '")` for a string.

### Demo

```js
let list = "none, inherit, circle, disc, decimal, lower-alpha, lower-latin, lower-greek, lower-roman, upper-alpha, upper-latin, upper-greek, upper-roman";
let str = `'${list.split(', ').join("', '")}'`;
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way using just the regexp -

```js
const list =
  "none, inherit, circle, disc, decimal, lower-alpha, lower-latin, lower-greek, lower-roman, upper-alpha, upper-latin, upper-greek, upper-roman"

const list2 =
  list.replace
    ( /([^,\s]+)(?=,\s*)?/g
    , t => `'${t}'`
    )
    
console.log(list2)
// 'none', 'inherit', 'circle', 'disc', 'decimal', 'lower-alpha', 'lower-latin', 'lower-greek', 'lower-roman', 'upper-alpha', 'upper-latin', 'upper-greek', 'upper-roman'
```